# collection.insert issue in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am tries to insert information to a collection in this time gets error as shown below :

Error :

```
[01:17:33.480] "Error :MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.Dcare_user.$UserId_1 dup key: { : null }"
```

Collection.js :

```
Dcare_User = new Meteor.Collection("dcare_user");
```

Js Code :

```
var doc = Dcare_User.insert({
         userid : UserId,
         firstname : fname,
         lastname : lname,
         dob : dob,
         address : address,
         phoneno : phno,
         city : city,
         state : state,
         country : country,
         zipcode : zipcode,
         ssn : ssn,
         roletype : permissions,
         isactive : isactive,
}, function( error, result) {  
     if ( error ) console.log ( "Error :"+error.reason ); //info about what went wrong 
     if ( result ) { 
       console.log ( "result="+result );//the _id of new object if successful                        
     }                     
});
```

I am new to meteor.So i didn't get any idea about this.So please help me.

Comment: 1) What is UserId? How do you define it? 2) Did you modify the database outside of Meteor somehow?

Comment: UserId is Manually end user entered number.And not modify and insert some records throug meteor mongo.@Hubert OG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

This error means:

- There is unique index on `Dcare_user.UserId`.
- There exists a document in the `Dcare_user` collection with `UserId` equal to `null`.
- You are trying to insert a new document with `UserId` equal to `null`.

It looks like an unique index was created on a field you are not using.

### Solution

Either you need to drop the database and start fresh, or keep the database and remove the index. The following solutions assume this is a development database created for you by the meteor environment:

---

#### Drop the database

If you wish to drop the database and start over, you can type the following into your terminal from your app's root directory (while meteor **is not** running):

```
$ meteor reset
```

#### Remove the index

If you wish to remove the index and keep your data you can connect to the mongo shell by typing the following into your terminal from your app's root directory (while meteor **is** running):

```
$ meteor mongo
```

Once you are in the shell, you can remove the index with this command:

```
> db.Dcare_user.dropIndex({UserId:1});
```