# Accounts-password issue: duplicate key error index: meteor.users.$emails.address_1

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I got following error only on production built. i have tested on development its works perfectly fine.

```
Exception while invoking method 'createUser' MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.users.$emails.address_1  dup key: { : "damianmiles@gmail.com" }
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/Steven/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:111)
    at MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:595)
    at Meteor.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:476)
    at Object.Accounts.insertUserDoc (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1021)
    at createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:557)
    at packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:577
    at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:171)
    at Object.Accounts._loginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:287)
    at Meteor.methods.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:563)
```

here is the code in /clients/lib/accounts.js file:

```
Template.register.events({
'submit #register-form' : function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = t.find('#signupFullName').value,
        email = trimInput(t.find('#signupEmail').value.toLowerCase()),
        subdomain = t.find('#signupSubdomain').value,
        password = t.find('#reenterpassword').value,
        repassword = t.find('#reenterpassword').value;

    if(password != repassword) {
        alert('Password not matches');
    }

    if (isValidPassword(password) == false || isEmail(email) == false) {
        return false;
    }


       Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password, profile: {name: name}}, function(err) {
           if (err) {
                alert(err.message);
           } else {
                alert('Account has been created.');

                Meteor.navigateTo('/ControlPanel');
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
           }
       });

       return false;
    }
}
```

});

development:
meteor: 0.8.1.1, Nodejs: v0.10.25

production:
MongoDB: 2.6.1 (32bit), NodeJS: v0.10.26

Answer (score 1):

This error means that:

1. There exists a unique index on `users.emails.address`.
2. A user exists with the email `'damianmiles@gmail.com'`.
3. You are attempting to insert a new user with the same email.

Having a unique index on your user emails is not added by default with meteor, but it's a perfectly reasonable thing to do. In fact, if you didn't have the index meteor would still prevent the new user from being created - but it would throw a different error.

If you connect to your production database and run:

```
> db.users.findOne({'emails.address': 'damianmiles@gmail.com'});
```

you should get back a result. What to do with this information is up to you - maybe remove the old user, try inserting with a different email address, etc.

For a similar question, also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374742/collection-insert-issue-in-meteor).

Comment: Thank you but its abnormal to have that error only in production

Comment: Indeed. I assumed the database you use in production is not the same one you use for development. Is that not the case?

Comment: it could be. Meteor is using mongodb 2.4.9 and on production: 2.6.1

Comment: Thank you David, i have downgraded the production mongo to 2.4.10 and its working just great now.